# How to show complete column information in derby DB

Tags: derby

I am unable to see complete certificate in derby database in CLI. I need to check the certificates before I proceed to do other stuffs.

How can I check whole breaking column info of certificates ?

Example:-

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIEwzCCAqsCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQXXXXYYYYYYYYYgdMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMRYwFAYD VQQIDA1OaWVkZXJzYWNoc2VuMREwDwYDVQ&`

After `&` there is lots more text.So derby put '&' and hide the long texts

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors/text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What sort of "certificate" are you working with?

Comment: @BryanPendleton its X509CertificateHolder, column definition 'clob' in my code.

Comment: Have you tried using something like SquirrelSQL to view your data? It has good support for viewing CLOB columns.

Comment: @BryanPendleton No idea about this. Although I can see data in Postgres but I need to check same on Derby